# IDisposable pattern snippet

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, code-snippets

How can edit the IDisposable Pattern Snippet?
Where can I find it?

It seems that only the VB code snippet is available
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VB\Snippets\1033\common code patterns\types\ImplementTheDisposeFinalizePattern.snippet"
But I am looking for the C# one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download it [**Dispose Snippet**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1541eff6-00fa-421a-8ce2-52e8b810ed9b)

> Installation is as easy as saving to the correct folder which changes
>   depending on your version of Visual Studio:
>
> 2005: C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Code
>   Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets
>
> 2008: C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Code
>   Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets
>
> 2010: C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Code
>   Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets
>
> 2012: C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Code
>   Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets
>
> 2013: C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Code
>   Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets